# Is there any performance reason to not use UserControls?

Tags: asp.net, performance, user-controls

Is there performance difference when using say 10 user controls on a page vs a page displaying the same data, but without user controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course a clean design with lots of object and classes suffers from performance

However, given today hardware cost..... I don't care

I can fix the problems of a good design with more hardware, but there is no hardware to fix a bad design ;)

So use as many user controls as you want

Answer (score 0):

A usercontrol is just another object. It might use a little more memory and a bit more time(because the object needs to be placed in memory to be used), but I guess they are so small that it will make no difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cost to using user controls, but it is negligible and the benefits far outweigh the cost..